# Полоса прокрутки Select

Tags: html, css, javascript

Как убрать у `select` полосу прокрутки, чтобы можно было прокручивать только полосу прокрутки не видно было, как это реализовать?

Comment: Расставьте точки, запятые. Ваш вопрос "по реке плывет кирпич деревянный как стекло"

Comment: "Как убрать у select полосу прокрутки, чтобы можно было прокручивать только полосу прокрутки" БРАВО!!

Answer (score 1):

Селекты, радиобаттоны и input type=file не поддаются стилизации через CSS. Поэтому единственный выход это использовать элемент-заменитель, а сам select скрывать и синхронизировать их друг с другом.

Comment: есть селект, много option, у селекта задана высота max-height: 100px; после того, как мы задали высоту, появляется полоса прокрутки, как скрыть полосу прокрутки, и чтобы можно было прокручивать без нее?

Answer (score -2):

```css
.bloc {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid grey 1px;
}
.bloc select {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: -5px -20px -5px -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc">
  <select name="year" size="3">
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2012" SELECTED>2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N8Brx/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/N8Brx/)

Comment: [WTF?][1] не проще было на стак ссылку скинуть?
 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531269/hide-vertical-scrollbar-in-select-element

Comment: это не то, прокрутки нету!

Comment: есть селект, много option, у селекта задана высота max-height: 100px; после того, как мы задали высоту, появляется полоса прокрутки, как скрыть полосу прокрутки, и чтобы можно было прокручивать без нее?

Comment: @amf1k нет прокрутки потому что size="5" и options тоже 5. Если size сделать 3 или добавить несколько пунктов то прокрутка будет.

Comment: а как это все реализовать на js, без блока <div class="bloc"></div>

Comment: зачем тут вообще js?